# Can I create an app or a bot in discord that send messages as it was me?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want an app/bot that reads the last message that were sent to a specific channel on a server that I participate and depending on the text I want to send a message to that same channel. The thing is, I want to do it in my name, not using a bot id. I know that you can create a bot using your own name and avatar but what I really want is to send a message using my own account. Is that possible? Could not find anything like that in the docs, maybe a missed something?

Comment: Nah the discord api does not allow that

Comment: You best option would be to have the application send a message via webhooks. Webhooks can set a username and a profile pic when sending a message. so you could more or less "mock" a user  The `bot` tag will still be included with the message though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you are even allowed to do this so I doubt the discord API would have support for this

[Discord Guidelines](https://discord.com/guidelines)

> "Do not use self-bots or user-bots. Each account must be associated with a human, not a bot. Self-bots put strain on Discord’s infrastructure and our ability to run our services. For more information, you can read our Developer Policies"

However, if you really wanted to do this you could use a macro at the risk of getting your account banned by discord if they found out. You could create a macro in python using the `pyautogui` module.